# How can I represent a rectangle projected in geographic longitude and latitude (`WGS84`) into a regular rectangle?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, map-projections

I have located the geographic longitud and latitude of a rectangle in google maps, and I'd like to rescale/transform it into a rectangle. Plotting long/lat shows me a parallelogram. I understand I need to transform the coordinates system but I could not manage how.

```r
rectangle <- data.frame(cbind(c(-2.9496687,-2.9486079,-2.9490788,-2.9501396,-2.9496687),c(43.2646848,43.2641405, 43.2636538,43.2641981,43.2646848)))
colnames(rectangle) <- c("Lon","Lat")

plot(rectangle,t="l")
```

Answer (score 2):

First change the data frame names to `x` and `y`:

```
 df<-data.frame(x=rectangle$Lon,y=rectangle$Lat)
```

Then convert it into a `Polygon` object:

```
library(raster)
a<-Polygon(df)
```

Then into a `Polygons` object (basically a Polygon list):

```
b<-Polygons(list(a),ID=1)
```

Then into a `SpatialPolygons`

```
c<-SpatialPolygons(list(b))
```

Now, to this element you can assign a coordinate reference system, lat-long in your case:

```
proj4string(c) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

And finally, after this, you can transform it:

```
d<-spTransform(c, CRS("+init=epsg:26978")) #Just an example, you can use any crs instead of 'epsg:26978'
```

Hope it helps.